# How to properly set 'Value' in a ManageData operation on Stellar-SDK in Python?

Tags: stellar-sdk, operations, python-sdk

I'm trying to set up a managedata operation. I added the following to my transaction:

```
.append_manage_data_op(data_name="Hello", data_value="World")
```

However, it doesn't go through. Apparently the correct syntax is data_value='Union[Keypair, str]'. So I tried this:

```
.append_manage_data_op(data_name="Hello", data_value='Union[keypair, "World"]')
```

But it still doesn't work. Note in the above code 'keypair' is a variable representing 'Keypair.from_secret(my_secret).

What is Union and do I need to replace it with something else to make the transaction go through?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't go through" can you be more specific? What is the error you see?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\Stellar-SDK\manage_data.py", line 8, in <module>
    account = Server.load_account(account_id=public_key)
TypeError: load_account() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: I can do "Server.load_account(self=" but I don't know what to put behind the '='

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to take a step back and fill in some Python basics before proceeding. Based on the error you posted in the comments, you aren't using the `Server` class correctly.

You need to create an instance of the `Server` class and then call the `load_account` method on that instance. See e.g. the [example](https://stellar-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_account.html) here from the Python Stellar SDK docs:

```
server = Server(horizon_url="https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org")
source = Keypair.from_secret("SBFZCHU5645DOKRWYBXVOXY2ELGJKFRX6VGGPRYUWHQ7PMXXJNDZFMKD")
destination = Keypair.random()

source_account = server.load_account(account_id=source.public_key)
```

To understand the more general concept, check out  https://stackoverflow.com/a/625098/143804 for a discussion of `self` in Python.